# How to Make VPN ignore one LAN domain

Tags: networking, vpn

I recently switched to using expressvpn.  Prior to this, I used PIA.  PIA did not have this issue, but I believe expressvpn is better overall.  Here is the situation:

I have a server computer that is on the network 192.168.1.1 along with all the other computers in the house (this is the ISP domain). I have a direct ethernet connection from my main computer to the server that is using network 192.168.10.1

The server uses ubuntu, the main uses windows. The issue is that when I have the vpn turned on within the server computer, I can no longer access the mapped server drive on the main computer. If I turn off the vpn, it works, but that is not an acceptable solution. I want the vpn active on both computers.

I know I could just map the network drive to the 192.168.1.1 domain, but I want my main computer to always have a dedicated connection regardless of what happens with the rest of the network.

Is there a way to get this to work?

Cheers.

Below is my `ipconfig` output:

```
Windows IP Configuration
Ethernet adapter Ethernet 7:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . :
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.124.0.138
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
Unknown adapter Local Area Connection 2:
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . :
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . : lan
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.220
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . :
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.1
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: I am also a user of expressvpn, This is what I think you said you want a computer that passes through another computer that is running the VPN to not be affected by the VPN. If this s the case you can not do that with expressvpn.

Comment: I want computer a to talk to computer b on network 1, without being able to connect to the internet (therefore having zero need for the vpn), because that is all happening for both computers on network 2 (which is where the vpn is active).

Comment: I can use expressvpn preferences set network_lock default and make all computers on the 192.168.1.1 domain connect to the server via 192.168.1.135, but my main still cannot connect via 192.168.10.2

Comment: Maybe the expressvpn support can help?